# Is there any way to increase memory assigned to jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pymc3

I am using python3.6

My jupyter notebook is crashing again and again when I try to run NUTS sampling in pymc3.

My laptop has 16gb and i7 I think it should be enough. I ran same code on 8gb and i7 laptop and it worked that time. Not able to fig out what the issue is in this one.

I have generated the config file for jupyter with this command

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

I am not able to fig out which parameter I need to modify to tackle this issue.

This is code I am using

```
with pm.Model() as model:
#hyperpriors
home = pm.Flat('home') #flat pdf is uninformative - means we have no idea
sd_att = pm.HalfStudentT('sd_att', nu=3, sd=2.5)
sd_def = pm.HalfStudentT('sd_def', nu=3, sd=2.5)
intercept = pm.Flat('intercept')

# team-specific model parameters
atts_star = pm.Normal("atts_star", mu=0, sd=sd_att, shape=num_teams)
defs_star = pm.Normal("defs_star", mu=0, sd=sd_def, shape=num_teams)

# To allow samples of expressions to be saved, we need to wrap them in pymc3 
Deterministic objects
atts = pm.Deterministic('atts', atts_star - tt.mean(atts_star))
defs = pm.Deterministic('defs', defs_star - tt.mean(defs_star))

# Assume exponential search on home_theta and away_theta. With pymc3, need to 
rely on theano.
# tt is theano.tensor.. why Sampyl may be easier to use..
home_theta = tt.exp(intercept + home + atts[home_team] + defs[away_team])  
away_theta = tt.exp(intercept + atts[away_team] + defs[home_team])

# likelihood of observed data
home_points = pm.Poisson('home_points', mu=home_theta, 
observed=observed_home_goals)
away_points = pm.Poisson('away_points', mu=away_theta, 
observed=observed_away_goals)
```

Also this is the error sc:

[image: 1st sc]

[image: 2nd sc]

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit Python?

Comment: 64 bit python .

Comment: Please extend your error description beyond 'is crashing'!

Comment: @KlausD. Added sc of the problem

Comment: How do you know that it's a memory problem?

Comment: Are you using the same versions of all packages on both machines?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes i am using same version. i didnt see any prob. its same code. thats why i though might be memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following command after activating your environment:

```
jupyter notebook --NotbookApp.iopub_Data_Rate_Limit=1e10
```

If you need more or less memory change 1e10. By default it is 1e6.

Comment: This si the general way to change memory assigned to Jupyter notebook. This will solve your problem if the cause of it is memory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not memory issue.

Jupyter was getting this error for many reasons like browser issues whenever it run on SAFARI this error raise. Same issue on Google Chrome if it is not default browser.

Jupyter right now do not work with tornado server version 6.0.1, use another version of tornado.