# JupyterLab Kernel Restarts when I load too much data

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm running a Notebook on JupyterLab. I am loading in some large Monte Carlo chains as numpy arrays which have the shape (500000, 150). I have 10 chains which I load into a list in the following way:

```
chains = []
for i in range(10):
    chain = np.loadtxt('my_chain_{}.txt'.format(i)) 
    chains.append(chain)
```

If I load 5 chains then all works well. If I try to load 10 chains, after about 6 or 7 I get the error:

```
Kernel Restarting
The kernel for my_code.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

I have tried loading the chains in different orders to make sure there is not a problem with any single chain. It always fails when loading number 6 or 7 no matter the order, so I think the chains themselves are fine.

I have also tried to load 5 chain in one list and then in the next cell try to load the other 5, but the fail still happens when I get to 6 or 7, even when I split like this.

So it seems like the problem is that I'm loading too much data into the Notebook or something like that. Does this seem right? Is there a work around?

Comment: You need more memory. What type of data is it? Numeric?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible that you are running out of memory, though unlikely that it's actually your system that is running out of memory (unless it's a very small system). It is typical behavior that if jupyter exceeds its memory limits, the kernel will die and restart, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948003/how-to-increase-jupyter-notebook-memory-limit), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202801/is-there-any-way-to-increase-memory-assigned-to-jupyter-notebook) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55097211/jupyter-notebook-kernal-keeps-dying-low-memory).

Consider that if you are using the `float64` datatype by default, the memory usage (in megabytes) per array is:
`N_rows * N_cols * 64 / 8 / 1024 / 1024`
For `N_rows = 500000` and `N_cols = 150`, that's 572 megabytes per array. You can verify this directly using `numpy`'s `dtype` and `nbytes` attributes (noting that the output is in bytes, not bits):

```
chain = np.loadtxt('my_chain_{}.txt'.format(i))
print(chain.dtype)
print(chain.nbytes / 1024 / 1024)
```

If you are trying to load 10 of these arrays, that's about 6 gigabytes.

One workaround is increasing the memory limits for jupyter, per the posts referenced above. Another simple workaround is using a less memory-intensive floating point datatype. If you don't really need the digits of accuracy afforded by `float64` (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) you could simply use a smaller floating point representation, e.g. `float32`

```
chain = np.loadtxt('my_chain_{}.txt'.format(i), dtype=np.float32) 
chains.append(chain)
```

Given that you can get to 6 or 7 already, halving the data usage of each chain should be enough to get you to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could be running out of memory.
Try to load the chains one by one and then concatenate them.

```
chains = []
for i in range(10):
    chain = np.loadtxt('my_chain_{}.txt'.format(i)) 
    chains.append(chain)
    if i > 0:
        chains = np.concatenate((chains[0], 
chains[1]), axis=0)
        chains.pop(1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Am I not already loading them one-by-one in my original code? We are both looping over a range of 10 and loading in the chains and then appending / concatenating them to a list or an array no?